# I wanna select specific text in parentheses using GREP in indesign

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I have a question regarding the grep.

In the following text :

*"there are 15 cats (**10** black cats, **3** white ones, and **2** grey), but 4 of them are missing."*

I wanna select the numbers but only the ones between parentheses (10, 3, and 2) And only the numbers. not the text nore the parentheses.

I've tried multiple syntax, some including lookbehind and lookahead positif but I can't manage to find the right awnser...

[**edit**] to be precise, what I want is to be able to apply a "character style" in the "grep style" section of "paragraph style" options.
so it can't be a script but a single line of grep.

[image: "grep style" section of "paragraph style" options]

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what are you really trying to accomplish? Is it just one isolated line of text, or a file of them? Could there be more than one set of parens on a line, and if so, do you want them all, or only the first? What if there are embedded parens? Or can that not happen? I'm not familiar with inDesign, but this sounds like a regex nightmare, so please be clear and complete in your description of what you have, and what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to gain. So here is a guess how you can apply the character style 'numbers' to the numbers between brackets with a script:

```
app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, [], UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT);

function main() {
    var founds = []; // all founds
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;


    // Step 1. Find all texts between brackets

    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '\\(.+?\\)';
    var texts_in_brakets = app.activeDocument.findGrep();


    // Step 2. Find numbers inside the all found texts

    while (text = texts_in_brakets.pop()) {
        app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '\\d+';
        var nums = text.findGrep();
        while (num = nums.shift()) founds.push(num);
    }


    // Step 3. Apply the character style 'numbers' to the found numbers

    var style = app.activeDocument.characterStyles.item('numbers');
    while (found = founds.pop()) found.applyCharacterStyle(style, true);
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and sorry if I wasn't clear but to be precise, what I want is to be able to apply a "character style" in the "grep style" section of  "paragraph style" options.

Comment: Then the answer is 'No'. I see no way to do it as a GREP-style of a paragraph.

Comment: crap, too bad! Well thanks for your awnser anyway, I realy apreciat.